# HBITMAP or HDC to uint8[]

Tags: winapi

I have obtained a screenshot by doing the following:

1. `GetDesktopWindow`
2. `GetDC`
3. `GetClientRect`
4. `CreateCompatibleBitmap`

This gives me a `HBITMAP`, I can optionally take it to `HDC` with:

5. `CreateCompatibleDC`

My goal was to end up with a uint8 byte array from either step 4 (`CreateCompatibleBitmap`) or step 5 (`CreateCompatibleDC`) is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new DC with `CreateCompatibleDC()`,  create a DIB (device-independent bitmap) for this DC with `CreateDIBSection()`, select the DIB in the new DC with `SelectObject()`, then copy from your original DC to the new DC with `BitBlt()`. The pointer retrieved by the `CreateDIBSection` will point to the raw data. This data is allocated by the system, which means you don't need to allocate it yourself, but it will be freed when you call `DeleteObject()` for the DIB.

Here is an example in C :

```
HDC hdcMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(yourDC);

BITMAPINFO bmi;

memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;    // top-down
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

HBITMAP hbmp;
COLORREF *pixelBuffer;
hbmp = CreateDIBSection( hdcMemoryDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (VOID**)&pixelBuffer, NULL, 0 );

SelectObject( hdcMemoryDC, hbmp );

BitBlt( hdcMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, yourDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );
```

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug very much, I tested it out though and it's acting funny. I stripped out the error checking and messy ctypes stuff to show you the basic calls. There are no errors. But `hbmp` is returned as not-null (it is pointer to `0x8c012925`) but `pixelBuffer` is returned as null, do you have any suspicions as to whats up? Thanks the stripped code (`memset` is taken care of etc) to show function calls and arguments is here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/858c407391369a5f814c

Comment: @Noitidart I can't reproduce this behavior using C. On my side, `pixelBuffer` always have a value if the call succeeded (`hbmp` valid). It's also what is written in the documentation. Are you sure the way you handle `pixelBuffer` in your JS is correct ?

Comment: Thanks much for fast reply @ElderBug I also suspect that I'm doing something wrong with pixelBuffer. I set it to be an array of COLOREF that is nWidth * nHeight * 4 long then i cast it to void** this is proper way?

Comment: @Noitidart `CreateDIBSection()` will return a pointer to a buffer. The allocation is done by the system, so mustn't create an array yourself.You should define a pointer, and pass the address of this pointer. It looked like it was done right in the code you linked, but I'm not sure since I never used a JS bind for winapi. It's probably safe to assume the error is in the code you wrote, maybe you can link additional relevant code to track the problem ?

Comment: Thanks i changed it up to that but  i switched it back to old way. This is the contents of my `bmi` does it look right to you thanks again so much for this: `"bmi:" "BITMAPINFO({"biSize": ctypes.UInt64("40"), "biWidth": ctypes.Int64("1280"), "biHeight": ctypes.Int64("-1024"), "biPlanes": 1, "biBitCount": 32, "biCompression": ctypes.UInt64("0"), "biSizeImage": ctypes.UInt64("0"), "biXPelsPerMeter": ctypes.Int64("0"), "biYPelsPerMeter": ctypes.Int64("0"), "biClrUsed": ctypes.UInt64("0"), "biClrImportant": ctypes.UInt64("0")}, [{"rgbBlue": 0, "rgbGreen": 0, "rgbRed": 0, "rgbReserved": 0}])"`

Comment: Please ignore the ctypes.Uint etc just the number inside is important :P and field names :P

Comment: @Noitidart This looks right. Except that all the `(U)Int64` should be 32, but maybe it's irrelevant because it's stored as 32-bit anyway ? If I'm not mistaken, you defined all the structures yourself ? It's probably relevant to link how you defined `BITMAPINFO`, but also the declaration of `CreateDIBSection()` (probable culprit).

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug ill post it in one sec :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76884/discussion-between-noitidart-and-elderbug).

Comment: Hi @ElderBug I posted the links the chat is that ok there were three links

Comment: Thanks again very much Elder for that help. I think i found a way to make it to the RGB sorting on the C side: https://github.com/jrmuizel/ddb-bench/blob/e4c950b3a6f02ac8757f8393f3e409274f007f71/dibsection.h#L23 and https://github.com/johnrobinsn/pxCore/blob/03cb3eb92fac4a45e84da3194ab49b5218d9d178/src/win/pxOffscreenNative.cpp#L41 im researching it :)

Comment: @Noitidart That looks like a good and realistic solution. Unrelated, I wondered if you can notice any difference if you use the screen DC instead of the mem DC for the `CreateDIBSection` parameter. If there is no difference, use the screen DC, it's probably better.

Comment: Thanks again Elder I just have to run for an appointment but when I come back I'll test that out and report back. :D

Comment: Hey @ElderBug! I figured out how to speed JS up so the byte swapping takes <10ms! So cool thank gawd! :D

Comment: @Noitidart Cool :) I took a look at your other post. At last you get something with decent performance !